# Correct way of using polyporphism in php?

Tags: php, oop, polymorphism, abstract-class

I'm new to object oriented php. And if there are no functions in the method testing() in the HumanClass, should i declare them as abstract?

```
<?php    
    class HumanClass
    {
        private $legs;
        private $hands;

        public function __construct($legs, $hands)
        {
            $this->legs = $legs;
            $this->hands = $hands;          
        }

         public function testing()
         {

         }       
    }

    class StudentClass extends HumanClass
    {
        private $books;


        public function __construct($legs, $hands, $books)
        {
            parent::__construct($legs, $hands);
            $this->books = $books;
        }



         public function testing()
         {
            echo "StudentClass called.";
         }       
    }

    function callClass(HumanClass $c)
    {
        $c->testing();
    } 

    $example = new StudentClass(4, 2, 1);
    callClass($a);  
?>
```

Is it possible to have something like this?

```
echo $a->testing();
```

instead of having another method to call testing().

Comment: is this a typo? `$this->legs = legs;` without `$` and some others

Comment: @John: what prevented you from checking PHP docs *first*?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given the code that you give, it's far from clear what the testing() function is supposed to do other than just exist for you to try things. The answer to that will also determine whether the versions in the baseclass should remain there as empty function.

There are other options, too, e.g. that the derived class first invokes the baseclass (extending), or that the baseclass doesn't contain an abstract or concrete such function but only the derived one does. Which to choose is up to the informed programmer to decide.